# Laravel bootstrap - Migration Error

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, migrate, seed

I am getting this eror-

```
    C:\WAMP\www\gtwhero [master]> php artisan migrate:make create_users_table

    Warning: require(C:\WAMP\www\gtwhero\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\WAMP\www\gtwhero\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

    Call Stack:
        0.0002     233352   1. {main}() C:\WAMP\www\gtwhero\artisan:0
        0.0006     236256   2. require('C:\WAMP\www\gtwhero\bootstrap\autoload.php') C:\WAMP\www\gtwhero\artisan:16


    Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\WAMP\www\gtwhero\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\WAMP\www\gtwhero\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

    Call Stack:
        0.0002     233352   1. {main}() C:\WAMP\www\gtwhero\artisan:0
        0.0006     236256   2. require('C:\WAMP\www\gtwhero\bootstrap\autoload.php') C:\WAMP\www\gtwhero\artisan:16
```

After rumming 
    php artisan migrate:make create_users_table

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Have you tried running `composer install` looks like you're missing some dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue when I deployed some files from a git repo, in that some of the essential Laravel files were not brought over as they were listed in my `.gitignore`.

Anyway, running `composer install` will ensure everything needed is there.

After that you should have no trouble running `php artisan migrate:make create_users_table`.